# window 7 desktop shared folders icon image

Tags: windows-7, desktop, desktop-computer, shared-folders

I am using windows 7 professional. And I have many folders saved on my desktop but every time I check them (shared folders), the small icon image would change, does anyone know why and is it a possible virus situation? I have AVG protection but not sure why it would change like that.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The added small pictures are called Overlay Icons.
Your problem is that you have several products that are competing
for the same icons.

You may see all your overlay icons in the registry.
Use `regedit` to go to this registry key :
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`.

You will see there multiple entries for most products.
For example if you have Dropbox installed, you will have `DropboxExt01`,
`DropboxExt02` and up to `DropboxExt10`, because Dropbox is greedy.

This is because only 15 such overlays are used by Windows,
so big companies have entered into the battle of the overlays,
each trying to needlessly multiply their entries so as to crowd out the others.

You may delete excessive icons, leaving only one per product,
but once you launch any of the products it may again try to crowd out
the others. The displayed overlay might simply belong to the
last product you launched.