# Windows Icon Overlay Limit

Tags: windows-10, icons, onedrive

I've tried to read as much about this as possible but I am confused...  Microsoft claims overlays are not the prefered method for conveying file metadata, but if this is true, why does OneDrive use a maximal number of overlays?  Also, I have found some posts from ~2017 that indicated OneDrive was using a "status" field for the file (I guess similar to "date modified", etc), but when I began using OneDrive recently, it did not automatically start displaying this status, but it did begin hogging all the overlays.  How do you prevent it from using overlays and use the "status" instead?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1334771/8672

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window 7 desktop shared folders icon image](https://superuser.com/questions/1334748/window-7-desktop-shared-folders-icon-image)

Comment: It is not a duplicate.  Microsoft has stated overlays are bad, but they still use them, like a whole bunch of them.  Not only that, everytime you reboot your computer OneDrive attempts to steal them all back with the bogus "finish installing message".  I want to disable it.  I also want to have the "status" column without using files on demand (i.e. I want them always downloaded).

Comment: Status column example:  https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/899003-status-column-missing-in-onedrive-folder-in-file-explorer/

Comment: MS claiming that Overlays should not be used: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=15723

Comment: Is it possible to do what I want?  I think the answer is no?